# Selenium IDE does not identifies the javascript tab menu or submenu

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide, submenu

I am recording a script, while doing so I have a tab which drop-downs the menu list after taking mouse-over on it. If I need to click on submenu which list down only after the mouse-over on the main Menu of the Tab then IDE doesn't records this process how can I identify that tab. I tried with click, clickAndWait, mousedown, mousedownat, select etc. but it doesn't worked.

If I inspect the tab having Main Menu name Demo and Test1, Test2, Test3 are submenues on it then it looks like-

```
<li ng-class="{'active': selectedTab =='demo'}" class="has-sub">
    <span class="submenu-button"></span>
    <a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>Demo</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="./#/demo/channelRight">Test1</a></li>
       <li><a href="./#/demo/supplierRight">Test2</a></li>
       <li><a href="./#/demo/noAdProgrammes">Test3</a></li>
       <li><a href="./#/demo/manageTrigger">Test4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```